# Can't run Ember.js in a page that has prototype.js

Tags: ember.js

When prototype.js loaded in the same page of ember Ember's initialization flow is distrupted and the internal Ember objects (Application, View etc) are undefined.
See sample project at https://github.com/eishay/starter-kit

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'each'
collect prototype.js:864
init Mixinember-0.9.5.js:5927
Mixin.create ember-0.9.5.js:6175
get ember-0.9.5.js:6394
(anonymous function)
```

With ember.min:

```
Enumerable.collect() at prototype.js:485
n() at ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
b.create() at ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
(anonymous function)() at ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
(anonymous function)() at ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
```

Edit:
Just saw a thread discussing it at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/453 no resolution

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to get Ember.js to load before prototype, you get this resolved.

Anything else looks really problematic, Ember.js is widely using map() and prototype.js seems to happily override it with it's own implementation (collect()).

Patching prototype is very simple, just replacing (for instance) .map to _map to get it play nicer, bit I understand this is out of the question in your case.

For what it's worth, here is updated prototype:
https://github.com/AvnerCohen/Prototype.js-map-patched

Note that some things are changed by now in prototype.js 1.7, but this one issue persists..

Comment: Thanks, but I'm embedding my javascript app in a hosted page which I have no control on. As I fixed the problem with array.prototype some other came along. I think I won't be able to use ember. See more details at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/453#issuecomment-4111293

Comment: Ember has a disable prototype switch, which makes it play nice with javascript builtin objects (Array, String, Function) or libraries modifying those: http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/